# Auto Logout Issue in Magento 2.4.4 when Accessing Review Report – Suspected Source in Controller and Block Files

Tags: admin, magento2.4, review, product-review, magento-2-commerce

I'm currently working with Magento Commerce 2.4.4p4, and I've encountered an issue when accessing "Marketing > All Reviews." Upon reaching the review page, it appears that the session is getting invalidated. Consequently, any interaction with the page or a simple refresh results in the user being automatically logged out.

I'm uncertain about the root cause of this problem, but I've traced it back to a specific location in the source code. The culprit seems to be the following line in the file `vendor/magento/module-review/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Index.php`:

```
$resultPage->addContent($resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Main::class));
```

My attempt to debug led me to the block file at vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Adminhtml/Main.php. However, I'm struggling to comprehend how the content in this file functions.

If anyone here has insights into both the solution for this issue and an understanding of its origin, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This issue happened due to corrupt data, checking on review_detail table on any weird data, theres 59191 record of it

Comment: After checking again, it is not actually due to corrupt data but instead abundant of data, I noticed whenever I delete >= 58450 of the data then the issue got fixed

Comment: Trying to figure out how do I filter to get only first 100 data in the review page just for testing but unable to figure out how, anybody can advice how to do this, I only manage to figure out the location of the source code in vendor but still unable to figure out how to wrote the filter here \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid